# How to reinstall/fix specific perl module on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, ubuntu-16.04, perl, dpkg

During an update, apt and dkpg returned the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libperl5.22:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libperl5.22:amd64
```

When I tried to use the prescribed fix, it returned:

```
user@Server:/# sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libperl5.22:amd64
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libperl5.22:amd64:
 perl depends on libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5).

dpkg: error processing package libperl5.22:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libperl5.22:amd64
```

I have never encountered this error before, not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reach for force options immediately. First attempt a reinstall (which also should preserve configuration)

```
apt-get install --reinstall libperl5.22
```

You will find this advice in several Ubuntu forums, [here's a mention on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/450620/402689).